# Does lightGBM requires the entire dataset in memory or Can it train the model by partially loading the data into memory?

Tags: boosting

I have a massive dataset -- ~120 M rows and 300 columns -- 
I want to use the entire dataset to train LightGBM.

Is there a way to train it using chunks of data sequentially?
If not what would you suggest to fully benefit this dataset? given that I have access to a 30GB RAM with 8 CPUs at most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not all that familiar with light GBM, but in general yes gradient boosting does require access to the full dataset. However, one option might be to take an ensemble approach. Split the data into multiple batches and train a model on each. Then at inference time simply make a prediction with each model using all the new data and take the average to get the final prediction.